# No "show" in the segue action list in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new to swift and IOS development.

system information: Xcode 6.1 Release Notes
                    OS X 10.10.1

My app has two view controllers, ViewA and ViewB, (No navigation controller), and I want to jump to ViewB from ViewA by click a UIButton in ViewA. The ViewA has been set as the initial view controller in the App.

By following some online instruction, I pressed ctrl and and drag the UIButton in ViewA to point to ViewB in the storyboard window. However, I got only a incomplete segue list (has only 4 item in total) as the following, in which I couldn't see the "show" item.

#

Action Segue
push
modal 
custom

#

It might looks like that in the old versions, but it is do in Xcode 6.1.

I saw some screen copies of the menu from the other people, they have much more items in their action segue list. Since no "show" available in my segue acton list, I used the "custom" item. It also helped me to jump to ViewB, but I got the following warning in compiling.

"Custom segues must have a custom class"
"Unsupported Configuration Custom segues must have a customer class"

My questions are: 
1) How can I access the build-in "show" time in the segue action list? 
2) Since everything works fine by so far, is there any to get ride of the warning message directly?

Please don't be hesitate the let me know if you require more information to identify the issues.

Since I'm new in iOS development, my questions might be kind of silly, but I do need your help.
I appreciate your effects with my questions.

Comment: It sounds like you turned off Size Classes.  Turn those back on if you want the other segue options.

Comment: You can turn on size classes by selecting your storyboard on the left most panel, going to View > Utilities > Show File Inspector, and clicking the Use Size Classes checkbox in the right panel. Full article: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html

Comment: Thanks a million, that is exactly I'm looking for. Love you guys.

Comment: Why does size classes need to be turned off for it to show?

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Xcode "Use Size Classes" is "Use Trait Variations".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go step by step for the process:

1. Make a new project. I used Single View Application for iPhone.
2. Add a second view controller to the storyboard (the panel on the left of the storyboard should look like this). If you don't see the panel click on the icon in the bottom left of the storyboard.

[image]

3. Drag a button to the storyboard

[image]

4. Hold control and drag from the button to empty space on the second view controller to get this menu.

[image]

5. Click show to make the segue.

[image]

6. If you already have a segue in place, you can change its type by clicking on it. On the right of the storyboard, you should have a panel with information on the segue. You can change the type from here. If you don't see the panel, click on the icon on the toolbar to pull it out.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your are right. I did got the menu as I started from the very beginning. Thank you very much.

Also as the comments suggested, I need to turn on the size class to access to the full segues menus.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, I think this has to be included as an answer (As this is the exact problem, many are facing).

**It sounds like you turned off Size Classes. Turn those back on if you want the other segue options.**

Hope it helps to anyone who is struggling with missing options.

Edit:

```
Size Classes have now been renamed to Trait Variations.
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was missing the new segue options and was scratching my head over that.... Size Classes have now been renamed to Trait Variations.