# Linking ViewControllers Using Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

When I searched up online, examples always come up with something different from what I end up getting. I'm not sure if it's because Swift updated but here is my problem: On websites when linking view controllers, people get the drop down menu that has (show,modal, custom, etc.) But when I do it I only get (push, modal and custom). By the looks of it, show is the one I need. So can someone please point me in the right direction? I have a feeling I might have unchecked something I'm not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adaptive segue in storyboard Xcode 6. Is push deprecated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184003/adaptive-segue-in-storyboard-xcode-6-is-push-deprecated)

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using, and which version of iOS are you targeting?

Comment: If you're using Xcode 6 or later, your issue may have been addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735431/no-show-in-the-segue-action-list-in-xcode-6-1. (turn Size Classes back on)